# how to make this "pattern match"?

Tags: python, regex

I have a output likes below:

```
ERT Statistics:
                    TEST1SF    TEST2SFE
                 ----------  ----------
  A2 BBBBBBB           3371           0
  A3 CCCCCCC              0           0
  afEF2                   0           0
  SEESE FESF             32           0
  EFESE 23Asf             0          34
  fwe34DS                 0           0
```

I want to use 're' in order to match each data row, likes ['A2 BBBBBBB','3371','0'] and ['A3 CCCCCCC','0','0']...

Just clarify, only data row need to matched. Because of i have different title format, to split them out have to consider each conditions... if there is 're' pattern to match data row directly, that would be good for me.

Ttile:

```
ERT Statistics:
                    TEST1SF    TEST2SFE
                 ----------  ----------

Data row:
      A2 BBBBBBB           3371           0
      A3 CCCCCCC              0           0
      afEF2                   0           0
      SEESE FESF             32           0
      EFESE 23Asf             0          34
      fwe34DS                 0           0
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: sounds like you just want to split on whitespace. row.split() will do it.

Comment: this is just a example, some of output they do not have title, or some of outputs they have different title format...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use something like [this](http://regexr.com?2vl8m):

```
^(.*?)\s*(\d+)\s*(\d+)$
```

or

```
^(.*?)\t*(\d+)\t*(\d+)$
```

with multi-line flag.